# Concatenating 2D plots

Tags: matlab, plot, concatenation, matlab-figure, legend

I have several 2D-plots in MATLAB. In each plot there are some lines (each line is a row-vector of values of fixed length). There is always a base line (black one) and the remaining colored lines may or may not be present.

[image: plot 1] , [image: plot 2].

I need to concatenate all such plots into one plot as shown below: [image: concatenated plot]

Please note these are just for representational purpose but explain my problem well. I am not able to figure how to do it. Anybody got an idea? An example may be? Also, there has to be a vertical gap between the successively concatenated plots as is shown in last figure.
Some points to note:

- y-axis is of fixed length for all plots
- if x-axis of each individual plot is 1:m. Then x-axis of final concatenated plot is 1:(n*m), where n is the number of individual plots to be concatenated.

Also, since each colored line corresponds to a specific kind of data, how to create its legend? Thanks!

Comment: If you want your final point on the `x`-axis to be `n*m`, then you can't have a vertical gap as this would introduce more points on the `x` axis.  However, you can do this but you would have to eliminate some of the points for each of your signals to make room for the vertical gap, and you can certainly make the last point on the `x` axis `n*m`.  If eliminating points on each signal isn't an option, then you will the final `x` point may have to be something like `n*m + 20` where we have 20 points to allow for all of the gaps in between the plots.  Is this something that could work?

Comment: @rayryeng i think if i choose not to plot line between the endpoint of first line and starting point of next this can be avoided. The x-axis would still be n*m. Isn't it?
lets say: plot(x(1:10));   plot(x(11:20)) and so on may be...

Comment: Doing `x(1:10)` then `x(11:20)` is the same as `x(1:20)`.  If you want to have a vertical gap and still keep the amount of points to be 20, you have to remove some of the points.  For example, if you want to have a 2 element gap between the two signals, you could do `x(1:9)`, then `x(12:20)`

Comment: just a small question, what labels do you want to have on the x-axis?

Comment: @natan - That's a perfectly valid question and I didn't think to ask that question myself!

Comment: @natan As i mentioned in the question, each individual plot as x-ticks as 1:m. Then concatenated plot has x-ticks: 1:(m*n). Any specific x-label is not required.

Comment: @rayryeng Are you sure plot(x(1:10)) followed by plot(x(11:20)) is same as plot(x(1:20))??

Comment: @learner - If you want to introduce no gaps at all, then yes they're equivalent.  If you want to introduce vertical gaps, then no they're not.

Comment: @rayryeng exactly! The vertical gap is needed...

Comment: @learner - In that case, then I can't see your data fitting into `n*m` points.  You will either have to eliminate some of the points in each of your signals to fit the data into `n*m` points to include those vertical gaps, or you will have to allow for an increase in your data to allow for the vertical gaps.  I'm not sure how else I can communicate this to you.

Comment: @rayryeng alright. Could you please tell me how to do that with allowing extra data then? I will look into it. It would also be helpful...

Comment: @rayryeng On a side note: this example shows how to remove line betwwen 2 specific points. The length of vector remains same. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754939/removing-the-line-between-two-specific-data-points-in-matlab)

Comment: That was the first suggestion that I made.  You'd have to not plot certain elements to introduce that vertical gap.  I guess there is a lost in translation thing happening somewhere.

Comment: I have two questions for you before I try to write an answer. (1) How are all of your data stored? Is each signal a row vector? (2) If (1) is yes, do you have some sort of naming convention that you use to distinguish between which plots belong to the same colour (referring to your plot)?

Comment: @rayryeng 1. yes, each signal is a row vector. lets say: signal = rand(1,15) is one signal. As per the figures, the x-axis is fixed 1:m, 'm' is the length of signal row-vector (so here m=15).
2. yes, each color is data-specific. There could be more than one orange-signals and same for others. So, each color represents a class. And the black is base class which is always present.

Comment: Is there a particular order you want these plotted?  For example, taking a look at your first photo you have shown, there are three plots in the first chunk, then 5 figures in the second chunk.  Do you have knowledge on what signals belongs to what chunks?  Are they named in a particular way? We can possibly do this vectorized but it's a bit difficult as you have provided very little information here.

Comment: @rayryeng I am sorry your last question is not clear. Its like, for one base class signal i get several predicted-class signals. And I plot it in one figure and then move on with 2nd base-class signal and its corresponding predicted signals. I need to concatenate all such figures...

Comment: @rayryeng if the gap is not possible, then I can easily add a vertical line at the joining point.

Comment: What is the naming convention for these signals? Do you have any code to show us that determines what these signals are?  I'd like to see how they're named so that I can be better equipped to concatenate these signals for you.

Comment: @rayryeng no specific naming convention. But, its like there are two for-loops. Outer loop for base-class and inner loop for corresponding predicted classes. So, for every iteration of outer loop, I have one base-class signal and several predicted-class signals. and I plot them in one figure. And so on for next iterations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options here: 1. concatenate to the same plot and pad with NaNs to obtain the gap. 2. actually have several plots and use `axes` in a clever way.

Here's an example for option 1, First we'll create some fake data:

```
a1=rand(1,20);
b1=3+rand(1,20);
c1=6+rand(1,20);

a2=rand(1,20);
b2=3+rand(1,20);
c2=6+rand(1,20);

a3=rand(1,20);
b3=3+rand(1,20);
c3=6+rand(1,20);
```

This is just for padding with NaNs...

```
f=@(x) [ NaN(1,round(numel(x)/5)) x ];
```

Concatenating:

```
y1=[f(a1) f(a2) f(a3)];
y2=[f(b1) f(b2) f(b3)];
y3=[f(c1) f(c2) f(c3)];
```

plotting

```
x=1:numel(y1);
plot(x,y1,x,y2,x,y3);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',[]);
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the example! I have a question, what if a2 is missing? According to my question above, each plot can differ in the no. of colored signals...

Comment: then represent it with a vector of `NaN`s with the known length of elements, for example `a2=NaN(1,numel(a1))` if `a1` and `a2` have the same number of elements...

Answer (score 2):

**This is regarding the `legend` part of your question:**

In order to have a single legend entry for several, separately-plotted items (the more accurate term would be "children of the axes object"), you should use [`hggroup`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hggroup.html). This way, plotted objects (such as lines) are grouped together (technically they become children of the `hggroup` instead of being children of the `axes` directly) thus allowing you to apply certain settings to the entire group simultaneously.

Here's a simple example of how this works:

```
%// Without hggroup
figure(1337); hold all;
x = linspace(-pi/2,pi/2,200);
for ind=1:3
    plot(x,sin(ind*x+ind),'DisplayName',...
         ['sin(' num2str(ind) 'x+' num2str(ind) ')']);
end
legend('-DynamicLegend','Location','NorthWest');
```

Results in:

[image: Plot with a dynamic legend without hggroup]

Whereas:

```
%// With hggroup
figure(1338); hold all;
x = linspace(-pi/2,pi/2,200);
prePlot=length(get(gca,'Children'));
for ind=1:3
    plot(x,sin(ind*x+ind),'DisplayName',...
         ['sin(' num2str(ind) 'x+' num2str(ind) ')']);
end
postPlot=length(get(gca,'Children'));
meshGrp = LegendGroupLatest(gca,postPlot-prePlot);
set(meshGrp,'DisplayName','Some sines');
legend('-DynamicLegend','Location','NorthWest');
```

Where `LegendGroupLatest` is:

```
function grpName=LegendGroupLatest(ax_handle,howMany)    
    grpName=hggroup; 
    tmp=get(ax_handle,'Children'); set(tmp(2:howMany+1),'Parent',grpName);
    set(get(get(grpName,'Annotation'),...
                'LegendInformation'),'IconDisplayStyle','on');
```

Results in:

[image: Plot with a dynamic legend including hggroup]

In this example, all lines that were plotted inside the loop get added to a single `hggroup` without affecting previously drawn items, and you can obviously add different logic to assign plots to groups.

Notice that a *dynamic* legend usually adds any `line` that is present in the chart (if you draw a zoom box in an axes that has a dynamic legend - the zoom box borders temporarily get added to the legend!), but `hggroup` prevents that.