# Legend in gplotmatrix

Tags: matlab, plot, legend, legend-properties

Given an `N x M` feature matrix `featMat` (for `M` features and `N` samples) and an `N x 1` class vector `classVec` we can nicely visualize this multivariate data with the help of [`gplotmatrix`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/gplotmatrix.html).

**Example:**

```
featMat = rand(10,3);
classVec = rand(10,1) > 0.3;
gplotmatrix(featMat, [], classVec, ['g','r']);
```

[image: example output for gplotmatrix]

**My Question:**
How can I control the legend of this plot? What I need is a *specific text with a specific color for each of the classes* appearing in my `classVec`.

**Comment:** One can replace the integer classVec by a cell array to control the text (e.g. `classVec = {'foo','bar','bar', ..., 'foo'}`). In this case I do not know how to control which class gets which color. This seems to depend on the appearance order in `classVec`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe this could help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875628/concatenating-2d-plots-matlab/25885777#25885777

Comment: @Dev-iL Thanks for your fast response. However, in a first test I could not directly set the legend with the `legend` command after plotting. I am sure it is possible to manipulate everything by "deeper" property manipulations, but I am expecting `gplotmatrix` to provide a natural way of setting its legend. I am sure it is quite easy. Shouldn't it? I just couldn't find the answer... :)

Comment: It seems like only one of the axes contains a legend... And even if this isn't the case, you could probably use findobj to get the legend handle. Which version of MATLAB is this btw?

Comment: @Dev-iL Matlab 2012b. Yap, you are right. I am just wondering why `gplotmatrix` doesn't seem to provide a more natural way to set its legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The legend created by `gplotmatrix` can be found because it has the `'Tag'` property set to `'legend'` (at least in Matlab R2010b). So:

```
featMat = rand(10,3);
classVec = rand(10,1) > 0.3;
gplotmatrix(featMat, [], classVec, ['g','r']);
h = findobj('Tag','legend');
set(h, 'String', {'Text1', 'Text2'})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works (for my Matlab 2012b)! This indeed is the "property manipulation solution" :)

Comment: @matheburg Yes, `gplotmatrix` should be able to handle this more naturally; or at least return a handle to the legend

Comment: One note: You should restrict the `findobj` to the figure of interest; otherwise all legend in all figures are effected by the `set`.