# Matlab legend: how to get one legend text for two data sets (lines)

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

Does anyone know how to group two data sets and give them one legend text? Actually I have four sets of data grouped by colors but different by line styles.
If I exaggerate a bit:

```
line 1 (LineStyle,'--',Color,'b')
line 2 (LineStyle,'-',Color,'b')

line 3 (LineStyle,'--',Color,'g')
line 4 (LineStyle,'-',Color,'g')
```

So, how to get first two lines will have common legend `text1` and second two common `text2`?

Comment: http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/display-one-legend-entry-for-group-of-objects.html

Comment: Also, this answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25885777/3372061

Comment: Is there any possibility to upload a picture even though I don't have enough reputation? If I could show you what kind of legend I want everything will be clear.